# irreducible infeasible set (IIS) in gurobi, from minizinc

Tags: gurobi, minizinc

Is there a way to get the IIS from Gurobi if I use it via the minizinc interface (i.e., mzn-gurobi) ?
Thanks, 
Ofer

Answer (score 1):

Currently no such option exists for `mzn-gurobi`. All available options can be seen by checking the help output: `mzn-gurobi -h`. Generally the options are for linear solvers (CBC, CPLEX, Gurobi) are shared. If you are missing this functionality, I would suggest making a feature request on the [MiniZinc repository](https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc). (Note that this functionality wouldn't be able to point to the constraints in the MiniZinc model, only the generated FlatZinc constraints)

What is in development within MiniZinc are **Minimal Unsatisfiable Sets**, which in my understanding are the same. A special kind of MiniZinc *solver* is in development that will give a subset of constraints, in MiniZinc, that violate a model. Although it seems development is going strong, it might be a while before this program will be released. If you have an immediate need for such a tool, you can try contacting the [MiniZinc Team](http://www.minizinc.org/team.html).